# Computation: an integral depending on parameters

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

> Compute
> $$
> I(a) = \int_0^{+\infty} \frac {\log^2(1+ax^2)}{x^4}\,\mathrm dx,
> $$
> where $a > 0$.

#### Attempts

Easy to see that this integral converges. Also easy to see that the following integrals are convergent as well, so we could take derivatives:
$$
I'(a) = \int_0^{+\infty} \frac {2 \log(1+ax^2)}{x^2(1+ax^2)} \,\mathrm dx,
$$
and
$$
\frac 12 I''(a) =\int_0^{+\infty}\frac 1{(1+ax^2)} \,\mathrm dx - \int_0^{+\infty} \frac {\log(1+ax^2)}{(1+ax^2)^2}\,\mathrm dx =: J(a) - K(a). 
$$
Now for $J$, I compute as follows:
\begin{align*}
J(a)&= \int_{+\infty}^0 \frac {t^4\,\mathrm d(t^{-1})}{(t^2+a)^2}\\
&= \int_0^{+\infty} \frac {\mathrm dt}{t^2+a} -\int_0^{+\infty}\frac {a\,\mathrm dt}{(t^2+a)^2} \\
&= \frac \pi 2\cdot \frac 1{\sqrt a} - a\int_0^{+\infty} \frac {\mathrm dt}{(t^2+a)^2},
\end{align*}
where
$$
\int_0^{+\infty}\frac {\mathrm dt}{(t^2+a)} = \int_0^{+\infty} -\frac \partial {\partial a} \frac 1{t^2+a} \,\mathrm dt = -\frac \partial {\partial a} \left(\frac \pi 2 \cdot \frac 1{\sqrt a}\right) = \frac \pi { 4a\sqrt a}, 
$$
so
$$
J(a) = \frac \pi {4 \sqrt a}. 
$$

#### Difficulty

How to calculate $K(a)$ then? By using Wolfram|Alpha, I get
$$
K(a) = \frac {\pi(2\log 2 -1)}{4\sqrt a}, 
$$
but I do not know what I can do to reach this result. Also the indefinite integral seems awful.

Any help is appreciated, including other possible methods to compute $I$. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I have solved this by myself.

**Solution**. $\blacktriangleleft$ First we integrate by parts
\begin{align*}
I(a) &= \int_0^{+\infty} \frac 13 \log^2(1 + ax^2) \,\mathrm d\left(x^{-3}\right) \\
&= \left.\frac {\log^2 (1 +ax^2)}{3x^3}\right|_{+\infty}^0 - \int_{+\infty}^0 \frac 13 x^{-3} \cdot 2\log(1 + ax^2) \cdot \frac {2ax}{1 + ax^2}\, \mathrm dx \\
&= \int_0^{+\infty} \frac {4a \log(1 + ax^2)}{3x^2 (1 + ax^2)} \,\mathrm dx. 
\end{align*}

Now taking the derivatives for $I(a)$, we have 
$$
I'(a) = \int_0^{+\infty} \frac {2 \log(1 + ax^2)x^2}{x^4(1 + ax^2)}\, \mathrm dx = \int_0^{+\infty} \frac {2 \log(1 + ax^2)}{x^2 (1+ ax^2)}\,\mathrm dx, 
$$
thus we have
$$
I(a) = \frac 23 aI'(a).
$$
Now we determine the initial value. Consider computing $I'(1)$:
\begin{align*}
I'(1) &= 2 \int_0^{+\infty} \frac {\log(1 + x^2)}{x^2(1+x^2)} \, \mathrm dx = 2\int_0^{+\infty} \frac {\log(1+ x^2 )}{x^2} \,\mathrm dx - 2 \int_0^{+\infty} \frac {\log(1 +x^2)}{1+x^2} \,\mathrm dx, \\
\int_0^{+\infty} \frac {\log(1+ x^2)}{x^2} \, \mathrm dx &= \int_{+\infty}^0 \log(1 + x^2) \,\mathrm d(x^{-1})\\
&= \left. \frac {\log(1+x^2)}x\right|_{+\infty}^0 +\int_0^{+\infty} \frac {2\,\mathrm dx}{1+ x^2} = \pi. 
\end{align*}
For the 2nd integral, we consider another integral with a parameter
$$
K(b) = \int_0^{+\infty} \frac {\log(1 + bx^2)}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm dx, 
$$
then $K(0) = 0$. Taking the derivative, we have 
\begin{align*}
K'(b) &= \int_0^{+\infty} \frac {x^2}{(1 + x^2) (1 +bx^2)} \,\mathrm dx = \int_0^{+\infty} \frac {t^{-2} \,\mathrm (t^{-1})}{(1 + t^{-2}) (1+bt^{-2})}\\
&= \int_0^{+\infty} \frac 1 {b-1}\left(\frac 1 {1+x^2} - \frac 1{b + x^2} \right) \, \mathrm dx \\
&= \frac 1 {b-1} \cdot \frac \pi 2 \left(1 - \frac 1{b^{1/2}}\right). 
\end{align*}
So by the fundamental theorem of Calculus, 
\begin{align*}
K(1) &= K(0) + \frac \pi 2\int_0^1 \frac {\sqrt b - 1}{(b-1) \sqrt b} \,\mathrm db = \frac \pi 2\int_0^1 \frac {\mathrm db}{\sqrt b(\sqrt b+1)} \\
&= \frac \pi 2 \int_0^1 \frac {2 \,\mathrm du}{u + 1} = \pi \log 2. 
\end{align*}
Thus 
$$
I'(1) = 2 \times \pi - 2 K(1) = 2\pi (1 - \log 2). 
$$
Now solve the initial problem 
$$
\begin{cases}
I'(a) = \frac 3{2a} I(a),\\
I'(1) = 2\pi (1 -\log 2),
\end{cases}
$$
we have
$$
\boxed{I(a) = \frac 43 a^{3/2}\pi (1 - \log 2)}. \blacktriangleright
$$